# Subquery with systables returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @Table nvarchar(150) = 'T_PROJEKT'
declare @Column nvarchar(max) =(
select STRING_AGG(CONCAT(col.name, ' ',  typ.name
                   , CASE
                        WHEN typ.name in ('nchar' , 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
                            THEN concat('(',col.max_length/2 , ')')
                        WHEN typ.name = 'datetime2'
                            THEN '(7)'
                        WHEN typ.name in ('decimal' , 'numeric')
                            THEN concat('(',col.precision , ',' ,col.scale, ')')
                        ELSE '' end), ',' )           
FROM sys.objects obj
JOIN sys.columns col on col.object_id = obj.object_id
JOIN sys.types typ ON col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
JOIN DISPO.T_TABELLEN dt on COALESCE(dt.OBJECT_ID_VIEW,dt.OBJECT_ID_HERKUNFT) = obj.object_id
                        AND dt.OBJECT_ID IS NULL
Where TAB_NAME = @Table
GROUP BY obj.name, SCH_NAME, TAB_NAME
)
```

This is the result:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>  Subquery returned more than 1
> value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Where can be my mistake? Any suggestions
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I suppose your table name exists in more than one schema and since you don't filter by schema name, you try to add multiple results into your variable @Column...

Comment: Presumably it's your inner join with `T_TABELLEN`. you don't use anything from this table so perhaps use `exists`

Comment: TAB_NAME is from T_TABELLEN

Comment: `GROUP BY obj.name, SCH_NAME, TAB_NAME` means you will get a row for each unique combination of those values. If for whatever reason your joins are returning more than one of them then that will explain the error. Given that `TAB_NAME` is fixed, one assumes that there are multiple rows with the same `obj.object_id` coming out of the join.

Answer (score 0):

Well the mistake is in the subquery as it states in error. So i would guess the error comes somewhere in between the case.
To pin point the issue some data would be very useful.
If you can't give any i would suggest you try using *TOP()* OR *MAX()* , where you think you get more results.